# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths doesn't update my cell data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableView in my ViewController.
One of the cell could be tap into another TableViewController to allow select a value.

I want to update my cell after back from the callee ViewController.

right now, i could pass back the selected value by delegate.

However, i tried following way, none of them works.

1. self.mainTable.reloadData()
2. ```
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
       self.mainTable.reloadData()
   }
   ```
3. ```
       self.mainTable.beginUpdates()
   self.mainTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
   self.mainTable.endUpdates()
   ```

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   was called and executed without error.

but the UI just doesn't change

here is the way I update value in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
            if let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell! {
            currentCell.textLabel?.text = address
            return currentCell
        }
```

Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let id = "Cell"
        println(indexPath)

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(id) as? UITableViewCell

            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: id)

                cell?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
                cell?.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
                cell?.contentView.addSubview(mapView!)

            }
            return cell!
        }else{

            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.address

            return cell
        }
    }
```

Here is the delegate method -

```
func passBackSelectedAddress(address: String) { 
    self.address = address 
    var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.mainTable.beginUpdates()    
    self.mainTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic) 
    self.mainTable.endUpdates() 
}
```

My fix:
After more debug, i find the cause,
the self.address value is updated in delegate, however it roll back to previous value in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I change the property to a static property, then resolve the problem.
I'm not sure what's wrong with instance property, and why it reverses back.

static var _address:String = ""

Comment: Don't call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You need to update your data model and then let the normal code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do its thing.

Comment: my model is just a simple String variable, i didn't call it at itself. i call it at 

my delegate
    // MARK: delegate
    func passBackSelectedAddress(address: String){
        self.address = address
        var indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)

        self.mainTable.beginUpdates()
        self.mainTable.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
        self.mainTable.endUpdates()
    }

Comment: Are you sure your delegate is being called?  Can you show your full `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: i'm sure it is called, i set the breakpoint, and it stopped. here is the code http://pastie.org/10406140

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code

Comment: i use facebook to login, and i didn't find a way to update the original question. but i paste the code in pastie.org above.

Comment: You can just click the word "edit" below the tags, but I can add the code for you

Comment: Thanks Paulw, find the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to grab a cell from the `UITableView` and then update the `textLabel` value that way. However, `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` are not meant to be updated in this way. Instead, store the value of `address` in your class and update this value when the delegate calls back into your class. If `cellForRowAtIndexPath` constructs the `UITableViewCell` with the value of `self.address`, calling `mainTable.reloadData()` after should update the cell to the new value.

For example:

```
var address: String

func delegateCompleted(address: String) {
    self.address = address
    self.mainTable.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(<your identifier>)

    if (indexPath == <your address cell indexPath>) {
        let textLabel = <get your textLabel from the cell>
        textLabel?.text = self.address
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: instead of get from current cell, i tried below as well, nothing changed. the cell value is still same            
            let cell = UITableViewCell()
            cell.textLabel?.text = self.address

Comment: I would advise you to read up on tutorials and documentation related to `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` and how they work together. You can either construct a `UITableViewCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and add the `UILabel` as a subview manually or use .xibs/Interface Builder to design the cell and specify a cell reuse identifier, then reference it in code to instantiate the cell and find the `UILabel`.

[Here is the documentation for UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/).

Comment: according to apple's doc, "If, however, notifying the user is not important—that is, you just want to change the value that a cell is displaying—you can get the cell for a particular row and set its new value." If i understand correctly, i could get the cell and update the value.

Comment: You must be using one of Apple's built in default style `UITableViewCell`s to utilize the built in textLabel property. Try using the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` constructor.

Comment: Thanks abouzek for helping.

Comment: Alright great. If one of us helped you please accept the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has some problems -

- You are using the same re-use identifier for different types of cell (one with a map, one without)
- When you allocate the table view cell for the other row, you don't include the re-use identifier.
- You have no way of referring to the map view that you are adding after the method exits because you don't keep a reference.

If you are using a storyboard then you should create the appropriate prototype cells and subclass(es) and assign the relevant cell reuse ids. If you aren't then I suggest you create a cell subclass and register the classes against the reuse identifiers. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will then look something like -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var returnCell:UITableViewCell


    if indexPath.row == 1 {
       var myMapCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mapCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as MYMapCell

       myMapCell.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center
       myMapCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
       // Set the properties for a map view in the cell rather than assigning adding an existing map view
       returnCell=myMapCell
    }else{

         returnCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("addressCell", forIndexPath:indexPath)
        returnCell.textLabel?.text = self.address

    }
    return returnCell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulw for helping